# match an array of empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to match the following condition in my JavaScript code:

```js
var a = [{}];

if (a === [{}]) {
  console.log('True');
} else {
  console.log('False');
}
```

it always prints `False`, why?

Comment: You can't compare an array, you could however use Lodash' `_.isEqual()` feature.
`_.isEqual(a, [{}])`. This will compare the individual object and return true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will compare two objects/arrays it will only return `true` if they have same reference in memory. `[]` will create a new array with different reference so it can't be equal to other.

```js
console.log([] === []) //false

let a = [];
let b = a;
//Now 'a' and 'b' have same reference

console.log(a === b) //true
```

To solve this problem you can check length of array and `length` of `Object.keys()` of its first element.

```js
var a = [{}];
if (a.length === 1 && typeof a[0] === "object" && Object.keys(a[0]).length === 0) {
   console.log('True');
} else {
   console.log('False');
}
```

You can also use `JSON.stringify()`

```js
var a = [{}];
if (JSON.stringify(a) === '[{}]') {
   console.log('True');
} else {
   console.log('False');
}
```